# In Vue.js app a lot of errors in the PhpStorm IDE

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm

I uploaded a Vue.js project in my PhpStorm 2019.2.3 and got a lot of errors in 
the IDE:

[image]

I suppose I need to set options here:

[image]

But which option have I to select? Have I to install some additive plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right option selected; the error comes from *JSHint* linter that doesn't support ES6 syntax by default.
You have to tell *JSHint* that your are using ES2015 syntax. This can be done by adding `/*jshint esversion: 6 */`
comment to your file (http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion), or by specifying

```
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

in `.jshintrc` file. If you don't have your own config file, you can modify the default preferences in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint** accordingly

- set *esversion* to *6*
- disable *es3* and *es5* options

[image]

If you didn't mean to use *JSHint* for linting your application (and I'd say that this linter is a bit outdated and doesn't work well with ES6/JSX), just disable it in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint**.
PhpStorm provides its own inspections and syntax analyzer, so you don't need using any additional tools for checking code quality. But, if you prefer to rely on some external linter, I'd suggest trying [ESLint](https://eslint.org/).